# nginx / fpm configuration with mixed paths

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I got a PHP application with Core in `/srv/myapp/src/www`.

This application can have plugins in `/srv/myapp/plugins/pluginname`.

Plugin's entry point is `/srv/myapp/plugins/pluginname/www` and corresponding url is something like `/pluginname/?arg=value`.

I can't figure out how to get a working nginx config with that. My base is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /srv/myapp/src/www;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

It's working well for all Core related URLs.

I tried to add the following for a given plugin:

```
 location /plugins/movies {
    alias /srv/myapp/plugins/movies/www;
    try_files $uri /plugins/movies/index.php?$args;
 }
```

It does work to serve static content (js assets & co) but any URL like `/plugins/movies/?id=12` gives a

```
2016/12/09 15:12:25 [error] 20491#0: *534 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.42.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /plugins/movies/index.php?id=12 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

How can I configure nginx to get it work ?

Comment: That is a truly bizarre layout for a web application. I would ask the developer to do something more sane, if possible.

Comment: It's historical and was rather easy to deal with with apache + mod_php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW here is how I fixed it:

```
    location /plugins/movies {
        alias /srv/myapp/plugins/movies/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ /plugins/movies/(.*\.php)$ {
        alias /srv/myapp/plugins/movies/www/$1;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename entered in `try_files` is always appended to the end of `alias` or `root` + `location` path.

So, with your configuration, URL `/plugins/movies/index.php?id=2` would correspond to `/srv/myapp/plugins/movies/www/plugins/movies/index.php?id=2`.

A quick though not an elegant fix is to use `location` block like this:

```
location /plugins/movies {
    alias /srv/myapp/plugins/movies/www;
    try_files $uri ../index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly it should even be `try_files $uri ../../index.php?$args;` but neither this form or the one you suggested does the trick. Don't you think there is sth to do with fastcgi config ?